# Determining whether 4 given vectors are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Is there any technique to solve this problem without a computer?

Comment: These are three dimensional vectors and they are $4$ in number so....?

Comment: [X-post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/271476/91764)

Comment: @AnuragA dependent?

Comment: Just a note: if a problem seems intractible to do some way, there's probably an easier way to do it.  Your professors aren't going to give you something you couldn't reasonably do in a few minutes.  Hence you probably shouldn't look for a means to explicitly find a nontrivial solution to $$\alpha_1\vec a + \alpha_2\vec b + \alpha_3\vec c + \alpha_4\vec d=\vec 0$$ That is liable to be very difficult.  Instead you should look for a way to guarantee linear (in)dependence *without* explicitly finding coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\vec a$, $\vec b$, $\vec c$, and $\vec d$ are $\mathbf{\color{blue}4}$ vectors in $\Bbb R^{\mathbf{\color{red}3}}$.  What's the dimension of $\Bbb R^3$?

**Solution:**

> Theorem That You Should Have Covered: If $V$ has a basis with $n$ elements then *every* set of vectors in $V$ which has more than $n$ elements is linearly dependent.
> This is the basis of the definition of dimension of a vector space.  In your particular case, one basis for the vector space $\Bbb R^3$ is $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$ and hence every set of vectors with more than $3$ elements *must* be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this vector set is linearly dependent. The minimal span of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is a set of three vectors, for example the column vectors in the identity matrix $\mathbf{I}_{3}$.

This is the shortest answer to the question of linear independence. However, you ask:
Can we show this without electronic help? Yes.

---

It's clear the instructor doesn't want you to rush to compute reduced row echelon form.  The irrational numbers are beautiful tags signaling that we should compare two pairs of vectors.

We have different paths, and present one option.

---

Compare vectors $a$ and $d$. The fact that $d_{2} =0$ reveals this vector is linearly independent of $a$.

Compare vectors $b$ and $d$. The second entries in each imply that $2b=c$, clearly refuted by the third entries.

We have two set of linearly independent vectors. Yet we only need three vectors for a span. Pick three vectors (here $a$, $d$, $c$) and express the fourth vector ($d$) in terms of this set.

---

That is, solve
$$
 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
  \xi & \xi & 1 + \xi \\
  1 & 0 & \pi \\
  \eta & \eta + 8 & \eta + 16
 \end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma
 \end{array} \right]
%
=
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \eta + \log_{3} \\ 2\pi \\ \eta + 16
 \end{array} \right]
$$

The existence of the solution proves the linear dependence of the full vector.

To conclude,
$$
\boxed{
 \alpha a + \beta d + \gamma c = d
}
$$